# "Incomplete Implementation" in xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode, implementation

I am getting an "incomplete implementation" warning on my ViewController.m file. no idea why. I have the code below. What am I missing?

#import "iaieDataViewController.h"

```
@interface iaieDataViewController ()

@end

@implementation iaieDataViewController ###ERROR HERE###

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say for us what you are missing, but you can easily find out yourself: go to the header file for your `iaieDataViewController`, and examine the methods declared by the class. For each method that you declare in the header there must be a method implemented in the .m file. Otherwise, you get an "incomplete implementation" warning.

Note that the methods of *protocols* that you adopt count as well: if the declaration has a list of protocol names (inside the `<` ... `>` brackets after the name of the class in the header), all required methods from these protocols must be implemented as well in order to avoid the warning.

Comment: Ahhh - I had added some code and then only deleted half of it - thanks!!